# PLSQL issue when updating with a value from an VARRAY

Tags: plsql, sql-update

I'm trying to learn some PLSQL and I've found myself trying to solve a simple problem that requires writing 'Odd' or 'Even' in the TEXT field if the COD number field is Odd or Even. Pretty straight-forward, right?

```
DECLARE
   TYPE possible_values IS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(10); 
   v_values possible_values;
BEGIN
   v_values := possible_values('Even','Odd');

   UPDATE ORG_TAB_PNU t
   SET t.text = v_values(MOD(t.cod, 2) + 1);


   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_values(MOD(20, 2) + 1));
 END;
```

Now, the problem seems to be this line of code:

```
SET t.text = v_values(MOD(t.cod, 2) + 1);
```

It is just fine if I say

```
SET t.text = v_values(MOD(1, 2));
```

or

```
SET t.text = MOD(t.cod, 2) + 1;
```

I can use any element of the array, or the value of the field t.cod, but i just can't use them together as it would return:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 8, column 31:
PLS-00201: identifier 'T.COD' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 8, column 18:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 7, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

What am I missing here? Have I misunderstood how an array works in plsql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PL/sql engine first trying to resolve `v_values(MOD(t.cod, 2) + 1)` and pass the value to SQL engine. But `t.cod` is unknown for pl/sql engine.

Workaround for this:

create stored function

```
   create or replace function odd_event(p number) return varchar2 
    is  
       TYPE possible_values IS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(10); 
       v_values possible_values := possible_values('Even','Odd'); 
    begin 
      return v_values(MOD(p, 2) + 1);
    end;  

   update ORG_TAB_PNU set text = odd_event(cod);
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL has table references (correlation names) scoped to just one level deep.

Take a look at this discussion [nesting limit for correlated subqueries](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:1853075500346799932)